# Surefire - exclude tests directory

Tags: java, junit, xunit, surefire

In my project tests are in maven package "java-tests-framework" (subpackage of the whole project) in two dirs:

```
/src/main/java
/src/test/java
```

I'd like to use surefire to run all tests only from the first directory. Here are the settings:

```
<testClassesDirectory>
    ${project.build.directory}/classes
</testClassesDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>
    ${basedir}/src/main/java-tests-framework
</testSourceDirectory>
```

But it runs tests both from first and second directories. Is there any way to exclude the last ones?

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude anything you want...

```
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/test/*</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
```

see [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).